# How can I create a directory on elastic beanstalk after deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble creating a directory for my logs on my .Net Core project after it's deployed on elastic beanstalk. The environment is windows server 2016. I have the folling script in my .ebextensions/install.config:

```
  "container_commands": {
    "create_app_data_dir": {
      "command": "mkdir C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data"
    },
    "create_logs_dir": {
      "command": "mkdir C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data\\Logs"
    },
    "set_iis_log_acl": {
      "command": "icacls \"C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data\\Logs\" /grant \"IIS AppPool\\DefaultAppPool\":(OI)(CI)M",
      "ignoreErrors": true
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that the directory might be being created but then overwritten again. I've also tried it with just 'commands' instead of 'container_commands'.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a folder called `.platform` in your root folder. Create a file called `00_myconf.config` inside `.platform` folder and add your configuration commands in it.

Please find the folder structure below.

```
.platform/
         00_myconf.config
```

**Content of `00_myconf.config`**

```
"container_commands": {
    "create_app_data_dir": {
      "command": "mkdir C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data"
    },
    "create_logs_dir": {
      "command": "mkdir C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data\\Logs"
    },
    "set_iis_log_acl": {
      "command": "icacls \"C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\CitilogikGatewayAdministration\\App_Data\\Logs\" /grant \"IIS AppPool\\DefaultAppPool\":(OI)(CI)M",
      "ignoreErrors": true
    }
  }
}
```

Redeploy your project and Elasticbeanstalk will execute the commands in the `00_myconf.config` every time Elasticbeanstalk creates new instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that script doesn't seem to run

Comment: Please check the logs and track what actually happening.

Comment: .platform is not created when redeploying

Comment: Please add .platform part of your code and commit it.